# Phantomjs with node gives "Promise pending"

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

When I run the script below from the command line `node script.js`, the result is:

```
success
Promise { <pending> }
```

The page never gets opened in `console.log`, can anyone explain why?

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage().then(function (page) {
    page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/').then(function (status) {
      console.log(status);
      var p = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
      });
      console.log(p);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as displayed, page.evaluate returns a promise.

try the folowing code :

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
    page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/').then(function(status) {
      console.log('test'+status);
      var p = page.evaluate(function () {
                 return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
             });
      p.then(function(pagecontent) {
        console.log(pagecontent);
        process.exit()
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're assigning Promise to a variable, and it's result is not returned immediately. You should rather:

```
page.evaluate(function () {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
}).then(function (html) {
  console.log(html);
});
```

Also, to not get lost in callback hell you might try to use `async/await` approach:

```
(async () => {
  const instance = await phantom.create();

  const page = await instance.createPage();

  const status = await page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');

  const html = await page.evaluate(function () {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
  });

  console.log(html);
})();
```

Which is kind of preferred way according to [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) maintainers guide.